# How do i remove the source path in doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I am using doxygen to generate a chm document for my header files. I have a problem in removing the path of the source (i.e header files) in my chm. For example if the path of my header files is c:\users\dx\Desktop\myprogram, my path seems to appear in the file reference, right below File List and File Members (i.e when i click on files -> and then on my header file name i am able to see the absolute path of my header files )
The link below is an image of a screen shot of the problem i am facing.

https://www.dropbox.com/sc/qzodmybui6nxub2/BeAqf7y2jM

How do i remove the directory reference, header file reference, how can i prevent those paths from displaying?

I tried removing source_browsers, verbatim_headers, strip_from_inc_path none of them worked

Thanks in advance.

Ps- Extremely sorry about the poor description, i hope the link would help to understand my problem

Answer (score 14):

Set FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES and STRIP_FROM_PATH = ../

The value passed to STRIP_FROM_PATH is dependent on where you are running doxygen from. I am assuming you are running doxygen in a subdirectory of the root of the source.

Comment: Sorry it didnt work, the problem seem to persist, any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you show me more of your directory structure? STRIP_FROM_PATH is suppose to contain whatever prefix path string that you want to remove. So if all your files have an extra c:\users\dx\Desktop\myprogram in front of it, then put STRIP_FROM_PATH=c:\users\dx\Desktop\myprogram . If that doesn't work change all \ to /.

Comment: @DanK According to the desciption for STRIP_FROM_PATH tag,  "If left blank the directory from which doxygen is run is used as the path to strip." It seems that your automatic strip didn't work. So there might be a difference of the left hand part of your code path and the directory where you ran your doxygen

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable Full_Path_Names
2. set the strip_from_ path and the strip_from_inc_path as the source path

e.g. if my header files are in a folder XX within a folder YY in the desktop, then MY STRIP FROM PATH and STRIP FROM INC PATH should be  C:\Users\dx\Desktop\YY\XX\