# How to change displayed include file path in doxygen API web page?

Tags: doxygen

I'm using doxygen for my C++ project documentation. The project's version related API is `version.hpp`, generated from `version.hpp.in` via cmake's `configure_file` commands. Thus, `version.hpp` is located in `@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`.

Here comes the question: I documented `version.hpp.in`, generated doxygen page from `version.hpp`, but I would like to mark the APIs' including path as `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` (a relative path), instead of `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` ( a full path). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is, mark the redundant directory prefix in Doxyfile.in

```
STRIP_FROM_PATH = @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/include
```

Reference:
[How do i remove the source path in doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423761/how-do-i-remove-the-source-path-in-doxygen)